# Formula for Description

Tags: excel-formula

I want to interpret my survey data using this interpretation
                           1.00 – 1.80 – Never
                           1.81 – 2.60 – Rarely
                           2.61 - 3.40 - Sometimes
                           3.41 - 4.20 - Often
                           4.21 – 5.00 - Always
Please help me with the correct formula if this is possible. Thank You!

I've already tried the IF function but i can't make it work.

```
=IF(AI3 < 1.80, "Never", 
    IF(AND(AI3 >=1.81, AI3 < 2.61), "Rarely", 
        IF(AND(AI3 >=2.61, AI3 < 3.41), "Sometimes" , 
            IF(AND(AI3 >=3.41, AI3 <4.21 ), "Rarely" 
                IF(AI3 >= 4.21, "Always", ""
                )
            )
         )
      )
   )
)
```

Comment: What is this formula you tried?

Comment: Use a lookup table with VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH.

Comment: =IF(AI3 < 1.80, "Never",  IF(AND(AI3 >=1.81, AI3 < 2.61), "Rarely", IF(AND(AI3 >=2.61, AI3 < 3.41), "Sometimes" , IF(AND(AI3 >=3.41, AI3 <4.21 ), "Rarely" IF(AI3  >= 4.21, "Always", ""))))))

Comment: I've tried that but nothing happens

Comment: Are you sure your values are numbers and not text or something else?

Comment: Here's the screenshot of the excel file: https://ibb.co/Bsk8Fjt

Answer (score 1):

So, using vlookup() or index() with match(), try this:

[image]
Formulae in B2 and B3 are:

```
=VLOOKUP($A$2,$A$4:$B$8,2,1)

INDEX(B4:B8,MATCH(A2,A4:A8,1))
```